# Where/how to store a collection of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a data set of timezones (see below) that I need access to in different parts of my app.

I'm used to an OO approach where I would store it in a class method e.g. in Timezone.all_zones (Ruby), accessible from anywhere.

Is it possible to do something similar, i.e. to have a component which sole purpose is to store this data and that I then can retrieve from different parts of my app?

Otherwise, what would be a more react way/location to store/retrieve this static data?

```
const timezone_objects = [
  {value: "-12.00", text: "(GMT -12:00) Eniwetok, Kwajalein"},
  {value: "-11.00", text: "(GMT -11:00) Midway Island, Samoa"},
  {value: "-10.00", text: "(GMT -10:00) Hawaii"},
  {value: "-9.00", text: "(GMT -9:00) Alaska"},
  {value: "-8.00", text: "(GMT -8:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)"},
  {value: "-7.00", text: "(GMT -7:00) Mountain Time (US &amp; Canada)"},
  {value: "-6.00", text: "(GMT -6:00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada), Mexico City"},
  {value: "-5.00", text: "(GMT -5:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada), Bogota, Lima"},
  {value: "-4.00", text: "(GMT -4:00) Atlantic Time (Canada), Caracas, La Paz"},
  {value: "-3.50", text: "(GMT -3:30) Newfoundland"},
  {value: "-3.00", text: "(GMT -3:00) Brazil, Buenos Aires, Georgetown"},
  {value: "-2.00", text: "(GMT -2:00) Mid-Atlantic"},
  {value: "-1.00", text: "(GMT -1:00 hour) Azores, Cape Verde Islands"},
  {value: "0.00", text: "(GMT) Western Europe Time, London, Lisbon, Casablanca"},
  {value: "1.00", text: "(GMT +1:00 hour) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris"},
  {value: "2.00", text: "(GMT +2:00) Kaliningrad, South Africa"},
  {value: "3.00", text: "(GMT +3:00) Baghdad, Riyadh, Moscow, St. Petersburg"},
  {value: "3.50", text: "(GMT +3:30) Tehran"},
  {value: "4.00", text: "(GMT +4:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat, Baku, Tbilisi"},
  {value: "4.50", text: "(GMT +4:30) Kabul"},
  {value: "5.00", text: "(GMT +5:00) Ekaterinburg, Islamabad, Karachi, Tashkent"},
  {value: "5.50", text: "(GMT +5:30) Bombay, Calcutta, Madras, New Delhi"},
  {value: "5.75", text: "(GMT +5:45) Kathmandu"},
  {value: "6.00", text: "(GMT +6:00) Almaty, Dhaka, Colombo"},
  {value: "7.00", text: "(GMT +7:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta"},
  {value: "8.00", text: "(GMT +8:00) Beijing, Perth, Singapore, Hong Kong"},
  {value: "9.00", text: "(GMT +9:00) Tokyo, Seoul, Osaka, Sapporo, Yakutsk"},
  {value: "9.50", text: "(GMT +9:30) Adelaide, Darwin"},
  {value: "10.00", text: "(GMT +10:00) Eastern Australia, Guam, Vladivostok"},
  {value: "11.00", text: "(GMT +11:00) Magadan, Solomon Islands, New Caledonia"},
  {value: "12.00", text: "(GMT +12:00) Auckland, Wellington, Fiji, Kamchatka"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a truly static resource, that will not be modified, you could put it in an own js file and import /require it in the components you need it.

Comment: Thank you. But out of curiosity, is there as well a "react way"?

Comment: I don't think there is, but maybe someone else does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [redux](http://redux.js.org/)

Otherwise for the static data, you make a data.js file:

```
export default function(){
    return[
        {value: "-12.00", text: "(GMT -12:00) Eniwetok, Kwajalein"},
        {value: "-11.00", text: "(GMT -11:00) Midway Island, Samoa"}
    ]
}
```

Then you can load it in you react app like this:

```
import getData from './data'
```

then for example in render method:

```
render(){
    console.log(getData())
    ...
```